# Vector and matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix

I have a question:  Given a vector $v=(1,0)$ and a matrix $A(φ)= \begin{pmatrix}
                                                               cos(φ)&-sin(φ)\\
                                                               sin(φ)&\phantom{-}cos(φ)\\
                                                               \end{pmatrix}$

I have to write a manipulate command for the value of the inner product $⟨v,A(φ)v⟩$, where $φ$ is in the interval $[0,2π]$. Than I have to plot a graph of $⟨v,A(φ)v⟩$. How can I make this? I have already tried using the `Manipulate[]` command, but how can I plot this? I have tried `Plot[{v,v.A(φ).v},{φ,0,2Pi}]` but it plots only the vector $v$. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Note that this is not a service where we will write all the code you need! Please give an idea of where you're stuck in this problem.  If you are a *Mathematica* beginner and don't know how to make matrices and vectors, then [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html) will be helpful. Inner products are done by using `Dot`.  Finally, for plotting, check out [this tutorial page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html).

Comment: You may define `A` by `A = t \[Function] {{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Henrik's function definition:

```
A = ϕ \[Function] {{Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ]}, {Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}};

v = {1,0};

Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[v.A[ϕ].v, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}], 
  ListPlot[{{ϕ, v.A[ϕ].v}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize -> Large}]], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]